# How do I edit this plugin to add a field in the shortcode?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, plugins

I'm working on this theme in Wordpress and attempting to edit the plugin so that in when added in Visual Composer it will ask the question how many posts would you like to display? I added this to the Attributes 'number_of_post' => '4', and added this 'posts_per_page' => $number_of_post, to the WP_Query Arguments and it still doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the actual code for the plugin:

```
//Work Area
function ratio_work_area( $atts , $content = null ){
 // Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(                                                                                                                 
            'sec_title_before' => 'Latest',                   
            'sec_title_after' => 'works',     
            'sec_btn_text' => 'See More Work',    
            'sec_btn_link' => '#',  
            'number_of_post' => '4',   
        ), $atts )
    );
ob_start();
?>

<!-- START PORTFOLIO -->    
<section id="portfolio" class="works_area section-padding"> 
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="section-title wow zoomIn">
                <h2><?php echo esc_html($sec_title_before);?> <span><?php echo esc_html($sec_title_after);?></span></h2>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="our_work_menu">

                    <?php $terms = get_terms('cat_portfolios');
                        if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
                    ?>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="filter wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1.5s" data-wow-delay=".25s" data-filter="all"><?php esc_html_e('All' , 'ratio');?></li>
                        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) :?>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter=".<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></li>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php }?>

                </div>              
            </div>

            <div class="work_all_item">
    <?php 

                // WP_Query arguments
                $args = array (
                    'post_type'              => array( 'portfolios' ),
                    'posts_per_page'              => $number_of_post,
                );

                // The Query
                $ratio_port_query = new WP_Query( $args );

                // The Loop
                if ( $ratio_port_query->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $ratio_port_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $ratio_port_query->the_post(); 
                        $ratio_port_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()),'ratio_image_1200_1200');
                        ?>
                        <?php 

                            $portfolio_terms = get_the_terms(get_the_id(), 'cat_portfolios');

                            if ( ! empty( $portfolio_terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $portfolio_terms ) ):

                                $portfolios_cat_slug = array();

                                foreach($portfolio_terms as $portfolio_term){
                                    $portfolios_cat_slug[] = $portfolio_term->slug ;
                                }

                                $portfolios_cat_array = join(" ", $portfolios_cat_slug);
                                $portfolios_class_array = join(" ", $portfolios_cat_slug);
                            endif;
                        ?>          

                        <div class="grid-item col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mix all <?php echo esc_attr($portfolios_class_array);?>">
                            <div class="single_our_work">
                                <div class="sing_work_photo">
                                    <figure>                                
                                        <img src="<?php echo esc_url($ratio_port_image['0']);?>" alt="">
                                        <div class="sing_work_text_link">
                                            <div class="sing_work_content_wrap">
                                                <div class="sing_work_content">                                                                                         
                                                    <div class="sing_link_img">
                                                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url($ratio_port_image['0']);?>" class="lightbox search" data-gall="gall-work"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="link"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                                    </div>  

                                                    <h5><?php the_title();?></h5>
                                                <?php $terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'cat_portfolios');
                                                        if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
                                                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <p><?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?></p>

                                                    <?php
                                                            }
                                                    } ?>                                                        
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>  
                                    </figure>
                                </div>              
                            </div>
                        </div>


                <?php   }
                } else {
                    // no posts found
                }

                // Restore original Post Data
                wp_reset_postdata();            

            ?>

            </div>              
        </div>
        <?php if($sec_btn_link){ ?>
            <div class="portfolio_btn text-center">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url($sec_btn_link);?>" class="btn-light-bg"><?php echo esc_html($sec_btn_text);?></a>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>          
</section>      
<!-- END PORTFOLIO -->  

<?php 
  return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode ('work_area', 'ratio_work_area' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use `'number_of_posts' => '4',`; You have missed letter **s**.
If that doesn't work, try to use **posts_per_page** instead of **number_of_posts**. It's depend on version you using.